# gwt pushButton in UiBinder

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I need to create a pushButton(so it's a button with image) in `gwt` with `UiBinder`, but I'm not sure how proceed. Here is my `ui.xml` code:

```
<g:PushButton ui:field="myPushButton"/>
```

And in *.java file I defined: 
`PushButton myPushButton;`

How can I add an image to the push button? I've tried the following but won't work:

```
<g:PushButton ui:field="myPushButton" image="myImage.gif" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You can use following code straight from CustomButton Javadoc:

```
g:PushButton ui:field='pushButton' enabled='true'>
   <g:upFace>
     <b>click me</b>
   </g:upFace>
   <g:upHoveringFace>
     <b>Click ME!</b>
   </g:upHoveringFace>

   <g:downFace image='{downButton}'/>
   <g:downHoveringFace image='{downButton}'/>
 </g:PushButton>
```

There's more in JavaDoc: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CustomButton.html