# hovering HTML help page over a link in GWT

Tags: gwt, hover

I'm trying to implement a hovering HTML help page over a link or widget in a GWT GUI.

I tried to do something similar to [change image on hover using gwt and ui-binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302621/change-image-on-hover-using-gwt-and-ui-binder) and http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Listeners~PopupListener

ui.xml

```
<layout:cell horizontalAlign="LEFT">
   <widget:ButtonLink ui:field="manageApps" text="Applications"/>
</layout:cell>
```

ui.java

```
PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel(true);
HTML html = new HTML("<p><a href="Hello" title="Hello">Hello</a></p>");
//popup.setStyleName("demo-popup");
popup.add(html);    

@UiHandler("manageApps")
public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
   popup.center();
}
```

However compilation fails on the @UiHandler with the message: Field manageApps doesn't have 'addHandler' method for com...MouseOverHandler.
Any idea or pointer helps. Thanks.

I have a solution so far that can be improved later:

ui.java

```
@Override
public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent mouseOverEvent) {
   //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
   popup.center();
}

manageApps.addHandler(this, MouseOverEvent.getType());
```

Comment: can you post your complete UiBinder file?

Answer (score 0):

What is a `ButtonLink`? If you made it yourself, did you implement `HasMouseOverHandlers`? Chances are the problem is that the widget doesn't know how to throw a `MouseOverEvent`, but you're trying to catch them anyway.

Comment: I have a solution so far that can be improved later:

ui.java

@Override
public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent mouseOverEvent) {
   //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
   popup.center();
}

manageApps.addHandler(this, MouseOverEvent.getType());

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution so far that can be improved later:

ui.java

```
@Override
public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent mouseOverEvent) {
   //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
   popup.center();
}

manageApps.addHandler(this, MouseOverEvent.getType());
```